# mapmyindia confused about how to get OAuth

Tags: mapmyindia-api

I have read the documentation for OAuth on [this website](https://www.mapmyindia.com/api/advanced-maps/doc/authentication-api.php).

But I am still confused about the format in which the request url is supposed to be in.

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following request url to generate the Access Token,

```
String URL = "https://outpost.mapmyindia.com/api/security/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id="+clientid+"&client_secret="+clientsecret;
```

And, add the following Headers in the POST Method,

> ("accept", "application/json")
>
> ("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

If you are using Volley Library to get the Access Token using the POST request,
you may pass the parameters as a HashMap as follows:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("accept", "application/json");
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they use Spring. And it requires `grant_type` to be passed as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. And the credentials in a header:

```
{
  'Authorization': `Basic ${base64Encode(clientId:clientSecret)}`,
}
```